# Handling checked exception in Mono flow

Tags: mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflow, webflux

Not sure how to handle checked exception in the Mono flow.

```
return Mono.when(monoPubs)
               .zipWhen((monos) -> repository.findById(...))
               .map((tuple) -> tuple.getT2())
               .zipWhen((org) -> createMap(org))
               .map((tuple) -> tuple.getT2())
               .zipWhen((map) -> emailService.sendEmail(...))
               .flatMap(response -> {
                   return Mono.just(userId);
               });
```

Here, the sendEmail method is declared with throws Exception.

```
public Mono<Boolean> sendEmail(...)
            throws MessagingException, IOException
```

So, How to handle this checked exception in the zipWhen flow.

Also, How to handle

> .zipWhen((map) -> emailService.sendEmail(...))

if the method returns void.

Answer (score 3):

You need to review implementation of the `sendEmail`. You cannot throw checked exceptions from the publisher and need to wrap any checked exception into an unchecked exception.

The `Exceptions` class provides a `propagate` method that could be used to wrap any checked exception into an unchecked exception.

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
    throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
}
```

As an alternative, you could use lombok `@SneakyThrows` to wrap non-reactive method.